# Jenkins - copy artifacts from another project - what does suffix do?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm using the "Copy artifacts from another project" plugin in jenkins. I was able to copy my desired artifacts to a `/jenkinsbin` directory. This directory will be an archive of all my jenkins built executables.

I want to use the "result variable suffix" to add a suffix to the artifact. For example, say I build projectA, and got an executable called `serverA`. I want the subsequent builds of the executable `serverA` to be  `/jenkinsbin/serverA.1`, `/jenkinsbin/serverA.2`, `/jenkinsbin/serverA.3`, so I that I can disambiguate which executable is from which build. I assumed "result variable suffix" is what I want. Is that correct?

---